# Jersey/Jersey-spring @Autowire not working anymore when introducing AspectJ and advice not executed

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, aspectj

Has anyone managed to get Jersey Working with AspectJ (From Spring) ?

In my example I have a jersey class in java/groovy:

```
@Component
@Path("/resource")
class Resource{

    @Autowired
    ResourceAccess resourceAccess 

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getResource(@QueryParam("name") String name){
        def res= resourceAccess.getResource(name)
        return res
    }

...
}
```

It works just fine, the resourceAccess is injected by Spring and /resource?name=test returns me the resource with the name test

BUT when I want to introduce AspectJ (AOP) in the game the resourceAccess object is not injected anymore and my Advice is not even executed.

I added  in applicationContext.xml and created my aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect{
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAspect.class);

    @Before("execution(* com.test.Resource.getResource(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.debug("logBefore() is running!");
    }
}
```

Remark: if I change the pointcut in the advice to target something else it is working fine again.

Is anyone able to help me on that issue?

Comment: Just curious...if you change your Resource class to Java, do you still get the problem?

Comment: yes I get the exact same

Comment: I would guess that your Resource class is not being exposed to the load time weaver, but I can't say why. I suggest that you post a question here: http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?31-AOP